# Why I can't debug with RubyMine?

Tags: rubymine

I try to debug with RubyMine, I just got this error:

```
/Users/Apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby -e at_exit{sleep(1)};$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/bin/rdebug-ide --disable-int-handler --evaluation-timeout 10 --rubymine-protocol-extensions --port 64387 --host 0.0.0.0 --dispatcher-port 64388 -- /Users/Apple/Documents/projects/project-website/bin/rails server webrick -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.6.0, debase 0.2.2.beta9, file filtering is supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:64387
-e:1:in `sleep': Interrupt
    from -e:1:in `block in <main>'
/Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:80:in `wait': Interrupt
    from /Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:80:in `block in prepare_debugger'
    from /Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:79:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:79:in `prepare_debugger'
    from /Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:85:in `debug_program'
    from /Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/bin/rdebug-ide:130:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)
```

Any idea?